# Function that recieves an array and returns if it can be made strictly increasing by removing only one of it's element

Tags: php, arrays

I'm currently working on a function as described in the tittle, where I need to get and array of X values and see if they get in a perfectly increasing order by removing one and only one of it's elements, the problem is that this must be made in PHP, while the logic seems to be adding up, even tried this on another language successfully, but it doesn't work on PHP probably due to my own limited knowledge, any help is appreciated.

Conditions:
If the array can be ordened by removing one and only one value, return `True`.

Arrays with only one element after the change are ordened by default.

Repeated numbers don't count as ordened.

```
<?php
function SequenciaCrescente($arr, $n){
    
    if($n == 2){
        return true;
    }
    
    $modify = 0;
    
    for($i=0; $i<$n-1; $i++) {
      if($arr[$i] >= $arr[$i+1] || $arr[$i] >= $arr[$i+2]){
        $modify++;
      }
      if($modify > 1)
        break;
    }
    
    if($arr[$n-2]>=$arr[$n-1])
      $modify++;    
    
    if($modify > 1)
      return false;
    
    return true;
}

$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6);
    $n = sizeof($arr);
    if (SequenciaCrescente($arr, $n) == true)
        echo "True";
    else
        echo "False";
?>
```

Example of arrays it should return True but returns False:
`1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 6`  and  `3, 5, 67, 98, 3`.

Comment: Please share input and expected outcome, vs. actual outcome. Make abundantly clear (the exact conditions to the logic) what exactly you're trying to accomplish and what does not work.

Comment: Added after the code.

Comment: So... why exactly should it print "No" - what conditions need to be fulfilled for a "Yes" vs. a "No"? And where do you call `function SequenciaCrescente()`?

Comment: The wrong function call is on me, but it does not change the problem, already fixed it in the code and here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Its pretty simple, run the loop to check the sequence, if not in order then increase the counter. Check if the counter is greater than 1, then break the loop. Finally check the last the values applying same logic.

And you are not calling your function, check() is not defined.

```
function SequenciaCrescente($arr, $n){

    $modify = 0;
    
    for($i=0; $i<$n-1; $i++) {
      if($arr[$i] >= $arr[$i+1])
        $modify++;
        
      if($modify > 1)
        break;
    }
    
    if($arr[$n-2]>=$arr[$n-1])
      $modify++;    
    
    if($modify > 1)
      return false;
    
    return true;
}

$arr = array(1,3,2,4);
    $n = sizeof($arr);
    if (SequenciaCrescente($arr, $n) == true)
        echo "Yes";
    else
        echo "No";
```

Comment: It works almost perfectly, but this code does let repeated numbers pass, thar was the reason why my code had an if dedicated to check if values are equal, but with your help I already proofed the code from it, thanks.

Comment: Try (>=), I have modified my answer, change as per your requirement while checking two values.

Comment: Did some dozen tests, the new code works better, but it let the following sequences slip past ```1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 6```, ```1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4```, ```40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30``` and blocked these that should be true ```1,1```, ```3, 5, 67, 98, 3```.

Comment: @LucasdaCostaSilva all this back an forth might have something to do with the unclear conditions for the logic. Show the exact conditions for a pass (yes) or fail (no) - edit your question please.

Comment: Edited the question with clear restrictions along with sequences it fails to solver properly.